# Converting an array into a String and vice versa in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array of objects that I need to convert into a simple String and then vice versa. 
Here is my code

```
var json1 = '{\"menu\": {'+
    '\"id\": \"file\",'+
    '\"value\": \"File\",'+
    '\"popup\": {'+
    '\"menuitem\": ['+
      '{\"value\": \"New\", \"onclick\": \"CreateNewDoc()\"},'+
      '{\"value\": \"Open\", \"onclick\": \"OpenDoc()\"},'+
      '{\"value\": \"Close\", \"onclick\": \"CloseDoc()\"}'+
    ']'+
    '}'+
    '}}';
    var arr = [];
    var o1 = {url : 'http://url1',data : 'data1', response : json1};
    var o2 = {url : 'http://url1',data : 'data2', response : json1};
    var o3 = {url : 'http://url1',data : 'data3', response : json1};
    var o4 = {url : 'http://url1',data : 'data4', response : json1};
    arr.push(o1);arr.push(o2);arr.push(o3);arr.push(o4);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: For the purposes of the displayed code, @TravisJ is right on the money. If you have an actual need to do what it says in your title, [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) are your friends.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) object?

```
var myobj = []; // any array or object
myobj = JSON.stringify(myobj);
typeof myobj; // "string"

myobj = JSON.parse(myobj);
typeof myobj; // "object"
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L08z7q3b/).

Comment: JSON.stringify and parse are your best friends

Comment: @PremierBromanov sure! But don't try them on a circular reference hahaha